# Standalone - GnuPG

Tags: windows-7, portable, gnupg

I might just be dumb, but according to http://www.gnupg.org/ there is a standalone (or portable) version that one can get of GnuPG. That is, there is a version of GnuPG that doesn't require any installation and which should be able to run from for example a USB-key.

However, I don't seem to be able to find it.

I am on 64 bit Windows 7 Home Premium edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used any of these so cannot vouch for them, but here's a few I found. Some of these are PGP tools:

[InstantCrypt](http://www.instantcrypt.com/downloads/index.php) says that has issues on Win 7.

[GnuPT](http://www.gnupt.de/site/index.php?lang=de&Itemid=516) is portable and claims to work with Windows 7. Website in German but when installed, it supports English.

[PPGP](http://ppgp.sourceforge.net/) uses Java.

I think the portable version of GnuPG is one that you'd need to compile yourself, possibly only with support for *nix.